# Unrecognized statement type. (near with)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query like below for get sum of purchase and sold traffic.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_time,'%d')AS date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN seller_id = 1 THEN visitor_quantity ELSE 0 END) AS totalSold, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN buyer_id = 1 THEN visitor_quantity ELSE 0 END) AS totalBought 
FROM `tbl_orders` 
WHERE buyer_id = 1 OR seller_id = 1 
GROUP BY DATE(order_time)
```

Its working fine and giving me result like below
[image]

Since I am looking for get all dates between provided date range with 0 if there no any record for that date.

So I am trying following query

```
with recursive all_dates(dt) as (
    -- anchor
    select '2021-12-01' dt
        union all 
    -- recursion with stop condition
    select dt + interval 1 day from all_dates where dt + interval 1 day <= '2021-12-31'
)SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_time,'%d')AS date,SUM(CASE 
    WHEN seller_id = 1 
    THEN visitor_quantity 
    ELSE 0 
END) AS totalSold, SUM(CASE 
    WHEN buyer_id = 1 
    THEN visitor_quantity 
    ELSE 0 
END) AS totalBought FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE buyer_id = 1 OR seller_id = 1 GROUP BY DATE(order_time)
```

I have found query tutorial [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52d242480c80feebac5675d04ac17ab5).

But its giving me error called `Unrecognized statement type. (near with)` in phpmyadmin and giving same result as above image.

my phpmyadmin and marialdb version information is like this.

[image]

Let me know if anyone here can help me for same

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your access library (libmysql - 5.6.43) is too ancient.

Comment: @Cid, its showing 10.3.32, its not ok?

Comment: @Cid MariaDB 10.3 knows about recursive CTEs. And pay attention - the error message is NOT message provided by MariaDB.

Comment: This is a PhpMyAdmin bug. It was fixed in 5.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PhpMyAdmin [bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/165). You need to upgrade to 5.5.0 to get the fix.

Comment: Hello Sir! I have tried same query with PHP but its still shows me only two dates called 18 and 19. So I think there something wrong with my query

Comment: That's an unrelated problem.

Comment: OK sir! Thanks a lot! Let me find the query solution of it. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing the `LEFT JOIN` between the CTE and table like in the tutorial you linked to.